# Commands out of sync for auto-generated query

Tags: mysql, etl

I am creating a program using C# to read a set of csv files (approx. 30 million), parse through for certain pieces of information, and add these data from the csv files to a set of MySQL database tables that I'm creating. A part of this is causing me some headache...

I have a table called `custId_nums` with a customer ID and the customer's name. Each customer then also has their own table with a single field `subvisitid` which represents each time they visited the business (a new row for each visit). Each time I find a customer in a csv file, I want to check if they have already been added to the database by checking for their `custId` in the `custId_nums` table. If they have NOT been added to the database, I want to add a new row to the customer database with their custid and name, and I also want to create a new table with `subvisitid` field.

An example of the query that I have C# generate is below, which would represent two customers.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `custs`.`custExists459156`()
BEGIN
   DECLARE numRows INT DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numRows FROM `custs`.`custId_nums` WHERE `custId` = 459156;
   SELECT numRows;
   IF numRows = 0 THEN
       CREATE TABLE `custs`.`459156_visits` (`subvisitid` int(11) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
       INSERT INTO `custs`.`custId_nums` (`custId`, `custName`) VALUES ('459156', 'fName lName');
       ALTER TABLE `custs`.`459156_visits`
           ADD PRIMARY KEY(`subvisitid`);
   ELSE
       UPDATE `custs`.`custId_nums` SET `custName` = 'fName lName' WHERE `custId_nums`.`custId` = 459156;
   END IF;
INSERT INTO `custs`.`459156_visits` (`subvisitid`) VALUES ('34800006');
END$$
CALL `custs`.`custExists459156`()$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `custs`.`custExists459156`$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `custs`.`custExists539642`()
BEGIN
   DECLARE numRows INT DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numRows FROM `custs`.`custId_nums` WHERE `custId` = 539642;
   SELECT numRows;
   IF numRows = 0 THEN
       CREATE TABLE `custs`.`539642_visits` (`subvisitid` int(11) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
       INSERT INTO `custs`.`custId_nums` (`custId`, `custName`) VALUES ('539642', 'fName2 lName2');
       ALTER TABLE `custs`.`539642_visits`
           ADD PRIMARY KEY(`subvisitid`);
   ELSE
       UPDATE `custs`.`custId_nums` SET `custName` = 'fName2 lName2' WHERE `custId_nums`.`custId` = 539642;
   END IF;
INSERT INTO `custs`.`539642_visits` (`subvisitid`) VALUES ('34800006');
END$$
CALL `custs`.`custExists539642`()$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `custs`.`custExists539642`$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Presently, I'm outputing the generated queries to a set of .sql files and then manually importing them using the phpmyadmin tool, but I'm getting the error below. I've tried copying the generated SQL and pasting it on the "SQL" page of my phpmyadmin tool. In either case, it will execute correctly if I only repeat the sequence three or four times (three or four new customers), but if I add more than that I get the following from phpmyadmin:

> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
> SQL query: Copy Edit Edit
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Why are you creating thousands and thousands of throw-away stored procedures? This seems reckless and completely unnecessary. "Each customer then also has their own table" also sounds like a huge mistake. Relational databases are supposed to *relate* data, not partition it arbitrarily into tables like that. If you must partition, consider using different databases, or if your database supports it, a different schema, if not regular old table partitioning.

Comment: @tadman That's true, and I want to do something less "reckless" in the future - this is early stages. With my somewhat limited knowledge of MySQL, I don't know how to check for a ```custId``` in my ```custId_nums``` table and, if it doesn't exist, create a table with that customers ID number in the table name. This was the solution I came up with, ugly as it is.

Comment: If it's early stages it's time to nip this schema in the bud and avoid it entirely. I've seen companies go down this road. The problem is as you scale up, the problem becomes geometrically harder to fix, often to the point where it's actually impossible to resolve, so you're stuck with this mess forecer.

Comment: Schema aside, why is this a stored procedure in the first place? This should be application code.

Comment: @tadman Fair enough. I need a way to look collect ```subvisitid``` numbers for each customer. That ```subvisitid``` is the name of a related table that contains a whole mess of information about that visit. In other words, I need to be able to take a ```custId```, look for each of the ```subvisitid``` numers associated with that customer, and then be able to pick information out of each of the ```subvisitid``` tables (each of which contains information about multiple customers).

Comment: Consider using `INSERT IGNORE` and a `UNIQUE` index. You can then attempt the insert and if it fails you'll get a result with 0 rows modified so you know it's a duplicate. This is safe from race conditions. Right now you test then insert, and it's possible that in the middle another process could insert a record.

Comment: See, this is why I love and hate StackOverflow in equal measure. I always get lots of help when I look on here, but whenever I ask a question I end up realizing just what a rank amateur I am!

Comment: That feeling of knowing nothing is part of the journey. The more you learn the more you'll learn about things you don't know anything about, that you didn't even know existed before.

Comment: Yep, so I've already abandoned this approach and re-arranged my tables accordingly so that 1. I have only 9 tables in total instead of many many thousands and 2.I don't have to deal with keeping track of each ```custId``` separately from each of their visits and the associated ```subvisitid```. Thanks @tadman for stopping me going down the wrong path.